# Where are legendary pokemon "banned"?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

I've read somewhere that Rayquaza and the other legendaries are banned somewhere (competitive gaming? battle arena? trainer hill?) Where are they "banned", and is Latios included in this?

Take note that I have no plans of going into internet battles or whatnot, and I am playing Emerald. I am trying to build up a good team and since I just captured a Latios, and I am wondering if I should include it in my team and replace one of my favorites, or just carry on with my 6 favorites?

Comment: I don't know Emerald, so I can't tell you *where*. But, from memory of how it worked in Ruby/Sapphire and how it works in later games, the ban used in places like Battle Tower affects Event-Only Pokémon (like Mew) and the story legendaries with 670 or higher base stat (like Kyogre, Mewtwo, and Rayquaza). Minor legendaries like Zapdos, Latios, and Heatran are typically allowed (which actually tends to be *not* in the player's favour).

Comment: why are they not in the player's favor? because they are also used by the other trainers?

Comment: Oh, yes. Oh very yes, they are. And sometimes in very, very nasty combinations. Latios, in particular for Ruby/Sapphire, is something of a nightmare if you have a very bad lead into it, and I'd expect the same for whatever its equivalent in Emerald should it exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In areas such as the Battle Frontier, the game puts restrictions on the Pokémon you can bring in. The Pokémon banned from the Battle Frontier in Emerald are:

- Mewtwo
- Mew
- Lugia
- Ho-Oh
- Celebi
- Kyogre
- Groudon
- Rayquaza
- Jirachi
- Deoxys
- Egg

In the competitive battling scene, Pokémon are categorized into different tiers. The most used tier is the [Smogon Tiers](http://www.smogon.com/dp/tiers/). The tiers are Uber, OU (overused), BL (borderline), UU (underused) and NU (neverused). Only NU Pokémon can be used in NU battles. NU and UU Pokémon can be used in UU battles, all the way up to Ubers where all Pokémon can be used.

*Note that tier lists change from generation to generation as Pokémon gain new movesets or counters.*

So to answer your question, Latios can be used in the Battle Frontier.

Comment: Really? [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Battle_Frontier_(Generation_III)) shows a ban list through all of the Battle Frontier.

Comment: Nevermind, I got Emerald and Crystal mixed up. *facepalm*